# Should I boil red potatoes before roasting them?

Tags: potatoes

I would like to try roasting red potatoes instead of regular idaho potatoes-should I boil and then roast or roast them raw? Also, covered in a ceramic container or uncovered--any tips?

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, it's a matter of how much time you have and what temperature your oven is set on already. I make these a lot, with a variety of dishes, so I've used multiple cooking methods.

**Ideal:** They roast best, I think, being boiled just for a few minutes then roasted at 475 F for 30 minutes.

**Oven's already on low:** If I have a more slow-cooking item already in the oven at 350 F, then I'll go ahead and put the potatoes in raw and leave them to roast for 60-90 minutes.

**Need them quickly:** When in a time crunch, I've also had success boiling them until softened completely then broiling until browned (maybe 5-10 minutes).

Answer (score 4):

You can go one of two ways with this and it's all going to depend on your preferences.

**They can be done as Tim said by simply tossing with butter or oil, seasoning and roasting until tender.**

***Benefit:***  Easy to prep and be done with.

***Drawback:***  They'll need to roast for about an hour (test by inserting a paring knife, if it inserts easily they're done) and they'll be more brown and shriveled.

**They can also be first par-boiled until a paring knife can be easily inserted and then tossed with butter/oil and seasoning before roasting.**

***Benefit:***  Less shrinkage, they'll retain more of the red color of their skin, and will only take about 15-20 minutes to crisp up the exterior.  They can be par-cooked, seasoned and refrigerated until ready to roast so are great for advance prep/entertaining.

***Drawback:***  A two-step process and the need to wash the pan used for first par-cooking them.

Answer (score 1):

I think reds are actually better for roasting. Cut the potatoes into quarters, toss them in melted butter and spices, put them in an open baking pan, and roast away.